# Nodejs terminal returning promise instead of value

Tags: node.js, async-await

If i write my code in file and run using

`node file.js`

it waits for file to run and then returns.

but if I write my code in terminal using below flow

`node`

`*paste code*`

`*press enter*`

it returns immediately a **promise**

code:

```
(async ()=> {
    var solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
    let data = await connection.getBlockHeight();
    return data
})()
```

how can I wait terminal to complete above process then return with the value?

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  ALL `async` functions return a promise that eventually resolves to some value.  They return that promise at the point of the first `await` in the `async` function.  The caller must use that promise to get the resolved value using `.then()` or `await`.

Comment: hey @jfriend00

if i try to .then() promise to another code similar to above one it still returns promise :/

`var solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
    let blockheight = connection.getBlockHeight().then((data)=>{
        return data
    })
    blockheight`

Comment: You would greatly benefit from learning how promises and `await` work.  I can't teach it all to you here in a comment.  You just aren't properly understanding how they work.  That `.then()` in your comment does nothing useful and doesn't add anything to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Await the async IIFE:

```js
await (async ()=> {
    var solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
    let data = await connection.getBlockHeight();
    return data
})()
```

or type the function body as it is without `return`:

```js
var solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'));
let data = await connection.getBlockHeight();
data;
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes the presence of top level `await` which will not be available in your either code block which is a CommonJS module using `require()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not a CommonJS module, it's a JavaScript expression evaluated by the [Node.js REPL](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl).